# Show Names Of Obsolete Snapshots In Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, snapshot

Is there any way to tell Jest to list the obsolete snapshots it has found when it outputs the message 'n obsolete snapshots found' while watching tests?

It give you the option to remove them, but not knowing exactly which snapshots have become obsolete makes this decision difficult.

Comment: True! You should open an issue !

Comment: Looks like you beat me to it. For anyone else that wants this implemented, go add some thumbs: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5005

Comment: This was solved in https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/5020 and should be ok with the new versions of jest.

Comment: They don't hang about!